# Renaming windows with python Xlib

Tags: python, xlib

Using the Xlib module for python, I have managed to move, resize, and destroy windows by calling configure() and destroy() respectively followed by display.sync().

However, I can't seem to rename existing windows. The following code outputs 'foo':

```
window.set_wm_name('foo')
window.set_wm_icon_name('foo')
print window.get_wm_name()
```

which would suggest that the object updates properly. On my screen, though, the window's title doesn't change at all, even after calling display.sync(). Am I using the set_wm_name functions correctly, if they should be used at all for this sort of task?

Answer (score 0):

I know im extremly late with this answer but maybe someone will find it usefull

```
from  Xlib.display import Display
from Xlib.Xatom import STRING


display = Display()
root = display.screen().root
#view the current WM_NAME
a = root.get_full_property(display.intern_atom('_NET_WM_NAME'), STRING)
print a.value
#Actualy change WM_NAME
root.change_property(display.intern_atom('_NET_WM_NAME'), STRING, 8, '  MyApp')


#read the name again
b = root.get_full_property(display.intern_atom('_NET_WM_NAME'), STRING)
print b.value
```

I've been unable to get window.get_wm_name()...Im sure im doing something wrong, but this works just as well :)